# IntelliJ Idea doesn't recognize .map files

Tags: intellij-idea, map-files

I'm working on a Spring Boot project. My project structure looks like this:

[image]

The .css files under 'css' directory are behaving like they're folders or packages. I tried to add the .map files manually but they are not recognized by Intellij.
I want the .map files to be on the same level as the .css files in order to avoid issues like wrong paths etc. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check "File Nesting" option: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-nesting-dialog.html